# Exception for the proof of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose a closed countour defined as:

$$
\begin{cases}
0 & y=1\mbox{, and,}0<x\leq1\\
1 & x=0\mbox{, and,}0\leq y\leq1\\
1 & x=1\mbox{, and,}0\leq y<1\\
x^{3}\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) & y=0\mbox{, and,}0<x<1
\end{cases}
$$

Where $z=x+iy$.

This would look like:

[image]

Near the origin the countour varies *infinite* times.

Now, in many proofs of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, we start with a triangle. We prove it for that case, then we generalize the theorem saying tha we can decompose any domain into triangles (intuitively, this is correct for most shapes).

But I can't see how this is possible near the origin, because it's too curvy (no triangule will fit there.

**Is this case not considered in the proof or my intuition is wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what proofs you have read, the ones I know proceed as follows:

1. (Goursat) the integral over the boundary of each triangle (or rectangle) vanishes.
2. From that follows that a holomorphic function defined on a convex domain (disk) has a primitive.
3. (Cauchy's integral theorem for convex domains/disks), in a convex domain (disk), the integral of a holomorphic function over a closed path vanishes. That follows directly from the existence of a primitive and the fundamental theorem of calculus. Let $f$ be the holomorphic function, and $F$ its primitive. If we parameterize the path $\gamma \colon [a,b]\to \Omega$, and let $a = t_0 < t_1 < \dotsc < t_n = b$ be a partition such that $\gamma\lvert_{[t_{k-1},t_k]}$ is continuously differentiable for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, then $$\begin{align}\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz &= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} (F\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n F(\gamma(t_k)) - F(\gamma(t_{k-1}))\\ &= F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a)).\end{align}$$ If the path is closed, the last difference is $0$.
4. Generalisation, all holomorphic functions have local primitives, and the integral of a holomorphic function over all null-homologous cycles vanishes.

At no point does one need to decompose a general contour into triangles, the existence of local primitives is the tool that yields all further results.

Comment: Can you spell out item 3. a bit more?

Comment: Sure, done. Would you think point 2. could use some elaboration too?

Comment: Well, it's not my question, but I think this question was rather aiming for this point 3.

Comment: Sounds like a very reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher I thought that for Cauchy theorem to hold the path must be rectifiable, I.e. such that its length is finite.

Comment: @lcv As far as I know, one considers only piecewise continuously differentiable paths. One can, if one really really wants to, generalise to rectifiable paths, but I haven't seen any situation where that was a good idea yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer well for instance, if one replaces $f$ with $f(x) = x \sin(1/x) $ in the suitable place the path is no longer rectifiable and Cauchy theorem might not work. This seemed to be the OP intention.

Comment: In that case, one uses the Cauchy integral theorem to define the integral over a non-rectifiable path. But, well, that makes the problem disappear in a different way.